# How to make Opera forget about a site

Tags: history, opera

When i start typing an address in the Opera url bar it helps me by putting full names of sites i've visited before which name starts from same letter i've just typed. For example if i type `g` it puts `google.com`, for `s` it would be `stackoverflow.com` and so forth. The question is how to make Opera forget that it's been there already and not put the site's name into the url bar? Cleaning history doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Which opera version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using the prediction service that can be turned off via the Settings > Privacy & Security screen.

Answer (score 0):

For Opera versions until 12.xx (not applicable for Opera 15.xx and higher)

There are two possible settings

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> → History → Set *Addresses* to 0
   This way you will never see inline completion regardless if its a bookmark or a history  entry
   Also, history entries are never displayed in Addressbar dropdown menu. Only bookmarks are.

   [image]
2. Go to `opera:config#UserPrefs|AddressbarInlineAutoCompletion` and uncheck it
   This way you disable *only* inline completion and you will still see history entries in your Addressbar dropdown menu
   [image]